# mySql: Export datetime type to csv- without ""

Tags: mysql, csv, export, quotes

I export data into csv file and I get the datetime cells with ""

for example when i open the csv file in notepad++ it shows me:
"2014-01-05 02:49:54"

does someone know how can i get the data without the quotes?
as 2014-01-05 02:49:54

thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using windows? It might have to do something with your regional settings.

Comment: I do use windows, but i think that it's something to do with the code..

Comment: What software are you using to export the table?

Comment: MySQL Workbench 6.1.7 CE